# Should multiple chapters share the same page?

Tags: publishing, character-development, microsoft-word, memoir

Now that my memoir is published, I notice how there are multiple chapters beginning sharing the same page that the previous chapter ended on. I don't like how it looks at all. Looking at other author's published books I notice that their book's are not the same way as mine, with multiple chapters sharing pages. Should multiple chapters be sharing the same pages?!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'd remove the part of your question about software recommendations, as a) questions here should focus on a single problem only, and b) whether any particular piece of software is better or worse on MS Word is a matter of opinion.

Comment: How did you publish your book?  If you went through a regular publisher, then the formatting should have been done by a professional and will have little to no connection to the format of your manuscript.  If you self published through a print on demand service, then you need to see what instructions the service gives you regarding formatting.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Word, Ctrl+Enter inserts a page break (moves on to a new page). There are also options in the 'Layout' tab for various types of section break, although I'm not fully sure what advantage these would have over normal page breaks (unless you're using the 'start on next odd-numbered page for example).

As per @F1Krazy's comment, whether or not you like MS word is purely a matter of opinion, but I know Google Docs offers similar features and there is a libreOffice alternative too (although I've never tried it). Try them and go with what you prefer.

Whether or not chapters should share a page is also somewhat case-specific. By 'multiple chapters' I assume you mean no more than two - I've only ever seen a chapter shorter than a page in one book before, and there it had a (very empty looking) page to itself (it was mainly as a joke, the chapter was called 'The Hunt for [Character]' and the only sentence was "Oh no wait there he is, didn't see him there for a minute."). Actually make that two books, because I know there are plenty of examples of multiple-chapter pages all through the Bible. Apart from those examples, I've seen some books where a chapter starts on the same page as a previous chapter ends, but it's not as common as just giving each chapter a new page to start on. Where it does happen tends to be (from memory) where the previous chapter finishes on a cliffhanger or similar so the narrative flows smoothly into the next chapter (rather than a break in time, place etc across the chapters). Moreover, those books also tend to use section breaks every few chapters which are much more defined, to break up the text a bit - structurally I certainly wouldn't advocate running the chapters together in this way all through a book. Have you asked the publisher about it?

Comment: Thank you kindly for answering my questions!

Comment: As it stands, this doesn't really address the main question, which is whether multiple chapters can share the same page. I'm not the downvoter, but that *may* have been what you were downvoted for. Would you be able to edit this to address the main question as well?

Comment: Thanks @F1Krazy for the helpful comment, edited in.

Answer (score 1):

No.   That would be bad formattng and layout.   Only if  you are trying to make it as short as possible when printed but then you would have better choices like different fonts to do that.